# How do I rotate the text/image in a widget button while keeping its dimensions?

Tags: android, button, android-widget

I've been looking for a solution for this problem for ages, and haven't been able to come up with a solution yet. I am developing a widget application which should be used on Android smartphones when driving in a car. The basic widget (home & lockscreen) is finished, now I want to tweak the layout so that it can be used in landscape mode as well.

I am not sure if this is correct, but when looking at the messages from my device (HTC One), when I change the orientation when in lockscreen / home screen, there is no message to indicate the orientation change. Thus it is not possible to determine which orientation is currently used, the widget will always be displayed in landscape mode. I think this is because it is a phone Android version, since the orientation changes in lockscreen and home screen on my Asus Nexus 7.

This makes my life easier and harder:

Easier because I don't have to implement animations for the rotation when the orientation changed. I can just implement three versions of my widget, one for each orientation (landscape, portrait, reverse landscape), which the user can choose from upon widget creation.

Harder because I need to find a way to rotate my buttons to the left and right. Since Android widgets provice only a limited set of layouts, and for example don't allow custom Button classes, this is harder than I thought.

This is what my portrait version looks like:

[image: Portrait]

This is what it looks like when I did the first few tweaks to the design, which is sopposed to be used when the device is being rotated 90°counter-clockwise:

[image: Landscape first tweaks]

As you can see, I tried to rotate the bottom parts to be visually appealing for the user. Rotating the speech button was no problem, but here comes the part where I'm stuck:

I want to have the four static buttons on top of the speech button. They are within a `LinearLayout` with horizontal orientation. Since I want to make the buttons as large as possible so the user can comfortable use the widget when driving, I have all widths and heights for the buttons set to `match_parent`. This way the buttons take up as much space as they can.
Now, I obviously have to rotate the text, so the user can read it when the phone is turned to landscape mode. But when rotating the buttons themselves, this is the result:

[image: Landscape rotated buttons]

As you can see, the height and width components are the same as before, the buttons are just rotated by 90 degrees. 
To fix this now, I would have to swap the values for width and height. Due to the restricted method collection of the `RemoteViews` object, this is currently not possible. 
The other way to fix the whole issue would be to only rotate the text. This, again, is not possible within the widget because of the restricted capabilities of the `RemoteViews` object.

The other way to achieve this layout-wise, would be to change orientation of `LinearLayout` to horizontal. Then rotate the layout itself by 90 degrees. This is what it looks like after. Still better, but since the height component is based on the non-rotated LinearLayout, the buttons are not filling the whole width of LinearLayout, plus are wider than the LinearLayout is high.

[image: Landscape rotated LinearLayout]

So, it seems the only way to achieve this is to rotate the text statically within the xml file. Doing it manually in my configure activity would only rotate it once, when the next update on the widgets is being performed, the xml-defined layout would be restored (Please correct me if wrong!).

I haven't found a way to change the text direction within the buttons, both `android:textAlignment` and `android:textDirection` do something different and don't help me.

Please guys, let me know if I missed something or if you have an idea... I have been searching the internet for hours and can't find a way of solving this.

PS: The solution should be usable for the ImageButton as well, it looks correct in my design but only because of the coincidental almost-square form of the button.

Comment: its very long to read ?............

Comment: It'a also a complex problem ;)

Comment: are you just trying to rotate the buttons and the text?

Comment: Basically I want to rotate the text while keeping the current dimensions of the buttons. When I rotate the buttons, picture number 3 shows that the text is correctly oriented, but the width and height have been rotated with it, subsequently. I want the buttons to stay the way they are in dimension, just rotate the text.

Comment: wouldn't it be easier to just rotate the entire view to landscape? I know it's not what you want but it would cut out a lot of individual layout changes

Comment: Yeah, I tried it but since widgets in Android on my phone are ALWAYS in portrait mode, it converts my layouts to portrait again. I had that before and it looked correct in the designer, but Android on the phone messed it up. This would definitely work for tablets and other devices that support rotation in home / lock screen.

Comment: No suggestions? I'll just apply the complete rotated views to my main activity now, since when users are e.g. using navigation on the phone, they can just switch to the app itself and don't need the actual widget. Would be nice to know if this is possible though.